# How can I access WhatsApp's conversation activity using contact data?

Tags: whatsapp

I'm an Android developer, How can I open Whats App conversation
 activity using contact data from my app?

Comment: What have you tried already? Could you provide more context to your question?

Comment: I tried with one Button. After clicking the button it will go to particular person whats app details page.